# Is there a way to declare external types that implicitly fit into another in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I want to target bytecode of a ES3 dialect. This ES3 dialect unfortunately uses types similiar to `number`, that implicitly convert to it, but differ in signature. The issue I've is that, for example, when implementing or overriding a method, if you specify a `uint` parameter as `number` and my TypeScript transformer outputs a method signature with the `number` type, the VM will throw a `VerifyError`.

The host environment implicitly converts between `Number` (auto-boxed, equivalent to TypeScript's `number`), `uint` (auto-boxed) and `int` (auto-boxed).

Basically I declare anything that takes `uint` or `int` as taking `number` instead, and my plan is to manually track `declare class`es that take `uint` or `int` and specially transform overriders or implementors into using these types instead. E.g.:

```
// let's say this class C comes from ActionScript.
declare class C {
    // equivalent external ActionScript signature:
    // function f(v: uint): void;
    f(v: number): void;
}
```

This could work, but then I've to track a list of anything that takes `uint` or `int`. I don't want to incentivate users to use these types, but it'd be easier if I could just do:

```
declare class uint { /* ... */ }
declare class int { /* ... */ }
```

And somehow tell TypeScript to implicitly convert between `number`, `uint` and `int`.

I'm also resetting all global objects (through `compilerOptions.lib = []`), so I'm manually defining `Number`:

```
declare class Number { /* ... */ }
```

Is it possible to tell TypeScript that these types implicitly convert to each other in the host environment?

---

I've tried follows. Works for `x`, but not for `y`:

```
declare class uint extends Number {}

declare function f(): uint;

const x: uint = 0;

const y: number = f(); // does not work
```

Comment: ① Is there a reason you're using `class` instead of `interface` or `type` here?  Is someone going to write `new uint()` or something?  ② I'm not sure I understand your use case; could you provide a [mre] that shows explicit input/output pairs you want to see, or lines of TS code you want to allow/prohibit, etc? ③ It sounds *sort of* like you want [nominal typings for different "types" of `number`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), as [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRjn1w), but I can't tell for sure.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz In the host environment, `uint(v)` is equivalent to `new uint(v)`, and `uint` is returned as a primitive. Maybe yes, I could try using `interface` as long as I can use the type as an object for type matching purposes (e.g. `const o = C;`), reflection (including name) doesn't matter though

Comment: Still don't understand the question.  Let me try a different approach: what, specifically, goes wrong if you just make `uint` and `int` aliases of `number`, and add whatever properties you want to the `Number` global interface as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mqp62N)?

Comment: @jcalz I think I might go with this, but then whenever I find a reference to e.g. `uint`, I've to treat it not the same as `number`. However it should be fine, as I know the source file it comes from. I suppose I can check if e.g. an `uint` type alias belongs to that source file where it comes from?

Comment: It seems like your problem isn't specifically about TypeScript the language but about some custom transformation you're performing, and without a [mre] I can actually test and play around with, I have very little, if any, advice to give.  I think I'll disengage now unless you [edit] the question to make it easier for others to test somehow (I'm not sure what that would look like unless the ES3 dialect is some publicly visible thing).  Good luck!